# Does the storyline end exactly at level 50 or it goes on?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm about level 40 with my character, and still in Act 2. I'm wondering if the storyline (Act 3 and Epilogue) finish pretty much exactly at the time you get the 50th level, or does the storyline continues for a couple of hours of gameplay after you reached the level cap?

Comment: I reached 50 waaaaay before the end.  I didn't do any PVP and only a couple flashpoints; mostly it was just from doing every bonus mission and sidequest, and space missions semi-regularly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've dinged 50 during the final class storyline mission on both of my level 50's, but based on conversations with others, that seems to be a lucky coincidence.

The class storyline continues through Corellia, the final planet, which is tuned for levels 48-50, and generally ends with a series of visits to class specific locales (think space stations, ships, obscure planet only for your class, that sort of thing), tuned for a max level or near max level character.

That said, you could easily hit 50 well before doing it if you have a lot of 'extracurricular (PvP, FP's, bonus series, space missions, etc.)' XP coming in, or get there much sooner with a high level buddy tagging along to kill things for you, so YMMV.

Comment: Sounds right, I'm 48.5 and still half way through Voss, so have 2 plants left to do!

Answer (score 3):

I have done both, hit 50 before finishing the class quest and finished the class quest before 50.